# elaboration freezes when assigning variable x:= x + y

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm trying to create a booth multiplier for an academic project and I'm having the weirdest error. Not sure whether this traces back to Quartus II or something to do with VHDL.

Everytime I try to Analyse and Elaborate the following code, the process freezes indefinitely (I've had it run for an hour already) at 46% of the Analysis  & Synthesis phase, in the console the last line is  `12127 Elaborating entity "booth_mul" for the top level hierarchy` without any other particular warnings or errors of note (just the usual (`found x design units,...`)

```
ARCHITECTURE booth_mul OF booth_mul IS
BEGIN
    process(Ain, Bin)
    variable result, toResult:      STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    --other variables
    begin
    --other stuff
    for i in 0 to 31 loop    
    --other stuff
            --toResult is the partial product being added to the result
            toResult := STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SHIFT_LEFT(UNSIGNED(toResult), i*2));
            result := result + toResult; --A&E Freezes if this line is included!!
        end loop;
        output <= result;
    end process;
END;
```

I've tried commenting out various parts of this and it's that line that is the problem. Is this a syntax problem with VHDL or with Quartus II itself?

using Quartus II 64-Bit Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 SJ Web Edition

**Update:**
I've provided the rest of my code but it doesn't seem like it should be at fault. The design does compile without errors, but only after nearly three hours. Here is the full design:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY booth_mul IS
    PORT
    (
        Ain :   IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
        Bin :  IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
        output :  OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END booth_mul;

ARCHITECTURE booth_mul OF booth_mul IS
BEGIN
    process(Ain, Bin)
    variable result, temp, toResult:    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    variable toAdd, toSub : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    begin
        toAdd := Ain;
        toSub := (0 - Ain);
        for i in 0 to 31 loop
            if i = 0 then
                if Bin(0) <= '1' then
                    toResult(31 downto 0):= toSub;
            end if;
            else 
                if (Bin(i) <= '1' and Bin(i-1) <='0') then
                    toResult(31 downto 0):= toSub;
                elsif (Bin(i) <= '0' and Bin(i-1) <='1') then
                    toResult(31 downto 0):= toAdd;
                end if;
            end if;
        --  
        --  --Sign Extension
            if toResult(31) <= '1' then
                toResult(63 downto 32) := x"11111111";
            else
                toResult(63 downto 32) := x"00000000";
            end if;
            toResult := STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SHIFT_LEFT(UNSIGNED(toResult), i*2));
            result := result + toResult; --A&E Freezes HERE!!
        end loop;
        output <= result;
    end process;
END;
```

Comment: Your question does not present a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I synthesised this on Quartus 13.1 web edition in 54 minutes on my 2014 i7 laptop. It's a lot of logic: 2082 logic elements.

Comment: Do you have any VHDL experience? You're writing the code as if it was code for a CPU. VHDL (especially when for synthesis) requires a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to any synth tools at work, so I'm speculating. However, you are trying to synthesise a *completely combinational* multiplier (I'm not sure if this is intentional or not), that is reasonably sized. I shudder at the resources required to implement that (and the resulting Fmax), which probably explains why the tool is taking so long.

Comment: Your answer  seems better as comment, providing an opinion for a question that does not present a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That `--other stuff` can be at issue, it can be a Quartus II issue (and not reporting running out of memory is an issue). The loop itself is capable of running (in simulation). the sample code is not a complete for performing as a Booth Multiplier. You could wonder if an hour is a sufficient time to wait. There are no constraints in evidence.

Comment: All fair points (though I'm not sure if the point about simulation is relevant)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an answer to the problem. The only reason it took so long, for reasons I don't understand, was because result was not initialized to anything. I tried adding a simple `result := x"0000000000000000";` at the beginning of the loop and it completed a & e in under 10 seconds without error. That was very frustrating.

If anyone could explain why that initialization was the issue, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you checked your synthesis results to ensure everything is being inferred correctly/simulated the design to make sure it is functionally correct? I would have thought doing that would make the statement `result := result + toResult;` irrelevant (you are no longer accumulating)

Comment: I just checked this; Adding the `result := x"0000000000000000";` line right after the start of the loop effectively wipes all your logic (almost nothing is being inferred)

Comment: @gsm I expect he's put the initialisation before the loop, where it is valid. It'll "work" for a suitable value of "work", but some variant of `product <= a * b;` would allow a synth tool to make use of the built-in multipliers for a much faster, smaller, simpler, more efficient result.

Comment: Interesting... Not sure what I expect the result to be, honestly. I wouldn't have thought the built-in hardware mults could be utilised in a combinational design? (I will check later though)

Comment: I placed the statement before the loop began, my apologies, poorly phrased. The result is `ain * Bin`

Comment: Whether the mults work in a combinational block may be FPGA dependent - for others, I'd embed `product <= a * b` in a clocked process and expect it to work.